# Google Groups - java API - Setting access level

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Groups in google apps has access levels, under advanced group settings.

Team, Announcement-Only, Restricted and Custom.  Does anyone know how i can set these access levels in the java API for groups?  I can't seem to find the available methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These access levels are deprecated. You need to use the [Group Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/) to manage finer grained access settings for the group.